# How to get all the data from a table in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to get all the data from a table in SQL.The following command can be used:

```
select * from table_name
```

But it seems that using * decreases effeciency, so is there any other way ?

Comment: Use direct fields recounting in query, like `SELECT foo, bar, baz, ... FROM t` - but it will not be much faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
 SELECT col_name1, col_name2, col_name3 from Table_Name
```

This approach is Good compare with `SELECT * from Table_Name`

The reason to use this approach is at some point, an extra column may be added to that table, and would cause unneeded data to be brought back from the query.

Why Not preferring `SELECT * from Table_Name` : Reference : [Why not preferring SELECT *](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2007/07/18/the-real-reason-select-queries-are-bad-index-coverage.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use following syntax:

```
SELECT fieldname1,fieldname2,fieldname3 FROM table_name;
```

You can also optimize it by using limit. Just fetch the number of record you wanted at once.

```
SELECT fieldname1,fieldname2,fieldname3 FROM table_name LIMIT 10;
```